# How to add a lens to a micro camera?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to add a lens Ex: [Moment Tele 58mm Lens](https://www.shopmoment.com/products/tele-58-mm-lens) to a micro camera like the Pixart sensor camera. Since the camera itself is small and on side of the board, it's difficult to create any sort of mount for the lens. It is also being used for testing so ease of removal and cheap materials. Any helpful ideas would be appreciated.

[Micro Camera Website](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/max78000fthr.html#eb-overview).

Lens from linked site:

[image: 58 mm lens]

Comment: it is difficult to imagine a solution to the problem when we cannot see the camera

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the link to the website